# nameField encrypted metadata not deploying correctly

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

We have enabled platform encryption and are deploying the `<encrypted>` tags for standard and custom fields on objects. However we are seeing an issue when trying to deploy for `<nameField>`. Any reason why it would be different?

```
<nameField>
        <encrypted>true</encrypted>
        <label>Legal Entity Name</label>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>Text</type>
    </nameField>
```

This works for custom fields

```
<fields>
        <fullName>Custom_Field__c</fullName>
        <description>Description</description>
        <encrypted>true</encrypted>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Custom Field</label>
        <length>32000</length>
        <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
        <trackHistory>false</trackHistory>
        <type>LongTextArea</type>
        <visibleLines>3</visibleLines>
    </fields>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not deploying correctly"? Do you get an error? Is it ignored? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I second that question - what exactly are you seeing?

Comment: what version are you deploying with? (i.e. in package.xml)

Comment: @sfdcfox it is being ignored, jwhelan just not seeing the change propagated, no errors being reported, cropredy 45.0

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding an "answer" to your question. This will make sure your question gets the attention it deserves.

Comment: Apologies for that @sfdcfox

Comment: Any ideas? @JohnWhelan

Answer (score 2):

From the comments to your question, you mention using v45.0 of the API. The `encrypted` tag was deprecated in v43.0[[1](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm#encrypted)] of the API. You should use `encryptionScheme` instead[[2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customfield.htm#encryptionScheme)] specified with what type of scheme you would like for the field. I'm not sure why the API is silently ignoring the `encryption` tag though, I'd expect it to report that as invalid.

Comment: please check my edit in my original post

Comment: The encrypted tag is deprecated.  You should be using EncryptionScheme tag.

Comment: @BryanAnderson Does using v45 and `encryptionScheme` work for you? If the `encrypted` tag works past v43, it's a bug in the system.

Comment: I guess my point is I have never used it for any of the other fields. I can try and see what happens

Comment: @BryanAnderson The `encrypted` tag was a simple boolean, while field encryption can actually be of several types, which is why `encryptionScheme` was introduced. A `true` value of `encrypted` maps to the `ProbabilisticEncryption` value for `encryptionScheme`.